# Why does "dynamic exception" guarantee cause overhead?

Tags: c++, c++11, throw, noexcept

In C++11 this is deprecated:

```
void foo() throw();
```

and replaced by

```
void foo() noexcept;
```

In [this article](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2010/n3051.html) it is explained that the reason for this (among others, that boil down to the same thing) is that

> C++ exception specifications are checked at runtime rather than at compile time, so they offer no programmer guarantees that all exceptions have been handled.

While this does make sense to me, I don't understand why `throw()` was checked dynamically in the first place, or why `noexcept` does not provide exception guarantee other than calling `std::terminate` instead of normal stack unwinding (which is not really a solid guarantee IMO).

Wouldn't it be possible to check whether exceptions are thrown or not **during compile time** and fail compilation if this happens? As I see it, there are basically three cases:

```
void foo() noexcept
{
    // 1. Trivial case
    throw myexcept();

    // 2. Try-catch case
    //    Necessary to check whether myexcept is derived
    //    from exception
    try 
    { 
        throw myexcept(); 
    } 
    catch(exception const & e)
    {}

    // 3. Nested function call
    //    Recursion necessary
    bar();
}
```

With templates in C++ being instantiated for every type, compiling applications takes forever anyways - so why not change `noexcept` to force the compiler to check whether exceptions are thrown during compile time?

The only difficulty I see is that a function may or may not throw depending on runtime states - but that function should not be allowed to call itself `noexcept` anyway in my opinion.

Am I missing something, or was the intent to not increase the compilation time further, or to go easy on the compiler developers?

Comment: There is no way for compiler to know whether, say, a library function that you call within your function throws an exception.

Comment: `throw()` is a guarantee the compiler makes to you. `noexcept` is a guarantee you make to the compiler.

Comment: @PetrBudnik: Of course there is, any function not marked as `noexcept` may `throw`.

Comment: @MatthieuM. Without even going into dynamic loading, do you suggest that C++11 compiler should refuse to COMPILE `void foo() noexcept( true ) { bar(); }`, where `bar()` is from a library created prior to the introduction of `noexcept` keyword?

Comment: @KerrekSB: You mean the compiler gives you the guarantee to [beat you senseless](http://www.gotw.ca/publications/mill22.htm) by calling terminate() if an exception is thrown nonetheless (and to violate all RAII expectations by not unwinding the stack) ?

Comment: @AdN: I think the idea behind `noexcept` is that on some platforms, if a scope block creates a variable that has a destructor and, while that variable is live, calls a method which might throw an exception, the code required to ensure that the destructor will get called even if an exception is thrown might introduce substantial overhead even when the function returns normally (with no exception thrown).  Only if the compiler knows no exception will be thrown can the overhead be avoided, and in general the only way for the compiler to know that is for the programmer to say so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think a lot of it came down to the fact that when exception specifications were being defined, compiler writers were well behind the power curve. Implementing C++98 as sufficiently complex that there's only ever been *one* compiler that even *claimed* to implement all its features. Every other compiler left out at least one major feature that was included in the standard. Most fairly openly admitted that they left out substantially more than that.

You also need to keep in mind that dynamic exception specifications were also considerably more complex than just `throw()`. It allows a programmer to specify an arbitrary set of types that can be thrown. Worse still, specifying that a function can throw `foo` means it can also throw anything derived from `foo` as well.

Enforcing exception specifications statically could have been done, but it would clearly have added quite a bit of extra work, and nobody was really sure what (if any) benefit it would provide. Under the circumstances, I think it was pretty easy for most to think that static enforcement was something that could be required later if there seemed to be enough use to justify the work. Changing from enforcing at run-time to compile-time wouldn't require modifying existing code, only existing implementations.

Another point is that I'm not sure there was ever really *strong* support of exception specifications anyway. I think there was general agreement on the basic idea, but when you get down to it, probably less about the details.

Bottom line: it was easy to mandate only dynamic enforcement, and leave static enforcement for later (if at all). Turns out, static enforcement probably wouldn't really add all that much positive in any case, so mandating it probably wouldn't have accomplished much anyway.